# Is Nito.AsyncEx's AsyncProducerConsumerQueue performant enough to handle gigabytes of bytes?

Tags: nito.asyncex

Is `AsyncProducerConsumerQueue<byte> (maxCount: 10*1024*204)` designed to handle gigabytes of bytes or is there a better way to create a streaming queue for a gigabyte of bytes? Is it better to put byte[] of some size into the queue?

It just sounds weird for me to call `await Dequeue` a billion times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsyncProducerConsumerQueue` - like all the other types in `AsyncEx` - is written for maintainability and correctness, not performance.

For a performant asynchronous queue, I recommend [Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels?view=netcore-3.1). You do still end up calling `await` lots of times, but Channels use `ValueTask<T>` which is very performant especially in the synchronous case.

Comment: If anybody comes around to read my question and this answer: it was not performant enough to await each single byte from the stream. We ended up putting byte arrays of 4096 bytes each into the channel which worked like a charm. Thanks again for pointing out channels Stephen!

Comment: @D.R.: Are you using something pre-.NET Core 3.0? [3.0 got some performance improvements that help Channels be even more efficient than they already were](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/performance-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/).

Comment: We're using .NET Framework 4.7.2 + the newest version of the System.Threading.Channels NuGet package. Don't know if they should've those improvements too.

Comment: @D.R.: No, those performance improvements are (and always will be) .NET Core only.

Comment: The performance improvements are very nice indeed, I see ratios of 0.3 to 0.5 in the synthetic benchmarks presented in the blog article. However, that's by far not fast enough to stream a gigabyte byte-by-byte through a channel. We've used a Writer->Channel->Reader->StreamContent->HttpClient->WebService set up to transfer 800MB in around 2min to a localhost web service (the streaming is was to blame). After switching to byte[] of 4096 bytes we're down to 8s (approx. what our loopback gives us at max rates).